# How to combined multiple NSString in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

Like the title. How to combined multiple `NSString` in Objective-C ?

```
NSString *SERVER_IP        = @"123.45.678.123";
NSString *PORT             = @"12345";
NSString *USER_ID             = @"123123-123123-123-123-123123";
```

I want to combined the above String in to URL , and I try to use the following code. But it seems didn't work...

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://%@:%@/user/%@",SERVER_IP,PORT,USER_ID];
```

How to combined multiple `NSString` in Objective-C ?

I am new to IOS...Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your coding is fine

```
NSString *SERVER_IP        = @"123.45.678.123";
NSString *PORT             = @"12345";
NSString *USER_ID          = @"123123-123123-123-123-123123";


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@:%@/user/%@",SERVER_IP,PORT,USER_ID];];
```

u need to convert `NSUrl` to `NSString`

```
NSString *myString = [url absoluteString];
```

Answer (score 4):

You were almost right ! You should do it like this :

```
NSString *SERVER_IP        = @"123.45.678.123";
NSString *PORT             = @"12345";
NSString *USER_ID          = @"123123-123123-123-123-123123";

NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@:%@/user/%@",SERVER_IP,PORT,USER_ID];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];
```